# Firebase security not working

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

Need help understanding what wrong with the "Tracking" rule.  I'm able to read that data even though it's marked as .read : false.

```
{
 "rules": {
   "User": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read":  "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        }
    },
    "Purchase": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read":  "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        }
    },
    "Parm": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    },
    "Tracking": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

This is being done on an IOS app. Here’s the code:

```
Firebase *ref = [FBase referenceForTrackingDeviceId:sysparm.deviceId]; 
[ref observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) { 
  if (snapshot.exists) { 
    DLog(@"got it"); 
  } else { 
    DLog(@"No data"); 
  } 
}];
```

From the debugger:

```
(lldb) po ref https://<My-Firebase>/Tracking/E8C0C8FB-DE20-4017-9C74-3A6DAD6D4DC7 (lldb) po snapshot.exists YES
```

Comment: Where are you able to read the data? Can you show the code that is reading and how (if at all) it is authenticating?

Comment: This is being done on an IOS app.

Here’s the code:
    `Firebase *ref = [FBase referenceForTrackingDeviceId:sysparm.deviceId];
 [ref observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists) {
                DLog(@"got it");
            } else {
                DLog(@"No data");
            }
   }];`


From the debugger:
(lldb) po ref
https://<My-Firebase>/Tracking/E8C0C8FB-DE20-4017-9C74-3A6DAD6D4DC7

(lldb) po snapshot.exists
YES

Comment: I added the code to your question. You can do that yourself by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36206401/edit) link under it. I can't yet see what your ref points to btw, can you add the actual URL (feel free to remove your database name, but leave the path).

Comment: Thanks Frank.  It's on top already - part of the code you added.  Look at heading "From the debugger:".  It includes the URL and also the value of "snapshot.exists".